# Win8: Accessing page elements in default.html outside of default.js

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have the following page elements within **default.html**:

```
<div id ="content">
   <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

And within **default.js:**

```
...     
args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().done(function()
{
   var theOutput = document.getElementById("output");
   theOutput.innerText = "This is the output";
}));
....
```

This successfully produces the app that just has the text "This is the output"

But if I move this into a new script **script.js:**

```
(function ()
{
  "use strict";

  var theOutput = document.getElementById("output");
  theOutput.innerText = "This is the output";
}());
```

And added script.js as a script reference in default.html:

```
<script src="/js/script.js"></script><script src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

I get the error

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'innerText' of undefined or null reference

How do I access the output div in other scripts outside of default.js?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out script.js needed to wait until the page elements were completely processed. The following code runs fine:

```
(function ()
{
   "use strict";
   WinJS.Utilities.ready(function ()
   {
     var theOutput = document.getElementById("output");
     theOutput.innerText = "This is the output";
   });
}());
```

Comment: You can use the same boilerplate `WinJS.UI.processAll()` code and it should also work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also handle the DOMContentLoaded Event which fires off once the DOM has been built (although images may have not fully loaded yet).  This is what I do in a lot of my canvas based Windows Store games.

Add this to the main function:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialize, false);
```

Then just do the code you want to fire off in initialize:

```
function initialize() {
    //Init Canvas
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```